# Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

## Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [path]: Failed to instantiate [path]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty.

## MoviesApplication.java

```
package dev.jeevan.movies;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class MoviesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MoviesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=movie-api-db
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://root:0000@cluster0.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.jeevan</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movies</name>
    <description>API for movie review</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

2023-06-04T18:13:59.002+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] dev.jeevan.movies.MoviesApplication      : Starting MoviesApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 3056 (F:\IntelliJ\movies\target\classes started by Jeeva in F:\IntelliJ\movies)
2023-06-04T18:13:59.002+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] dev.jeevan.movies.MoviesApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-04T18:13:59.142+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-04T18:13:59.142+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-04T18:14:00.592+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-04T18:14:00.634+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 23 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2023-06-04T18:14:01.744+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-04T18:14:01.760+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-04T18:14:01.760+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-04T18:14:01.890+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-04T18:14:01.893+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2749 ms
2023-06-04T18:14:02.762+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [pwc.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-9prlkfl-shard-00-00.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-06-04T18:14:02.762+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.9.1"}, "os": {"type": "Windows", "name": "Windows 10", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "10.0"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/19.0.2+7-44"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='root', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@25a5527f, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@56c98c9f]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=cluster0.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net, srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-ixrxqo-shard-0', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2023-06-04T18:14:02.803+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [pwc.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-9prlkfl-shard-00-01.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-06-04T18:14:02.803+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [pwc.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-9prlkfl-shard-00-02.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-06-04T18:14:03.111+05:30  WARN 3056 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty
2023-06-04T18:14:03.111+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-04T18:14:03.143+05:30  INFO 3056 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-04T18:14:03.206+05:30 ERROR 3056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at dev.jeevan.movies.MoviesApplication.main(MoviesApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:294) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.<init>(MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tried to connect to mongodb got **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory'**

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Need to add database name at end of the uri

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://root:0000@cluster0.9w5qpwc.mongodb.net/movie-api-db
```